# C++ Listview single row listed multiple times

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

[image]I have 6 rows of companies that I want listed into a ListView control.

Originally, my code was this to add columns:

```
LvCol.pszText = header1; //wchar_t header
LvCol.cx = 0x80;
LvCol.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM;
SendMessage(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 0, (LPARAM)&LvCol);
```

and this to add subitems:

```
item.iSubItem = 0;
SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&item);
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item.pszText = col1;
item.cchTextMax = wcslen(item.pszText);
SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&item);
```

And that worked fine to get it started.

Now, I would like to automatically loop through all the companies in my `std::vector` list of companies so it'll be better code, however I am stuck.

If I write my code this way:

```
size_t numColumns = Columns.size(); //Columns is an std vector that I add subitem headers 
size_t numRows = companiesInGame.size(); //std::vector company data that needs to be shown
size_t numTableCells = numColumns * numRows;

LVITEM tableCell = { 0 };
memset(&tableCell, 0, sizeof(tableCell));

for (int x = 0; x < numRows; x++)
{
    tableCell.iItem = x ;
    tableCell.iSubItem = 0;
    tableCell.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tableCell);
    for (int y = 0; y < numColumns; y++)
    {
        tableCell.iSubItem = y;
        tableCell.pszText = TableData[y];
        tableCell.cchTextMax = (int)wcslen(tableCell.pszText);
        SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tableCell);
    }
}
```

The first line gets properly implemented,  however it duplicates it. In my head, it should be this way:

```
size_t numColumns = Columns.size();
size_t numRows = companiesInGame.size();
size_t numTableCells = numColumns * numRows;

for (int x = 0; x < numRows; x++)
{
    tableCell.iItem = x ;
    tableCell.iSubItem = 0;
    tableCell.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tableCell);
    for (int y = 0; y < numTableCells; y++)
    {
        tableCell.iSubItem = y;
        tableCell.pszText = TableData[y];
        tableCell.cchTextMax = (int)wcslen(tableCell.pszText);
        SendMessageW(ListCompanyInfoTable, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tableCell);
    }
}
```

The `iSubItem` properly reads & increments every item that needs to be displayed, however I can't figure out how to increment `iItem` so that it will add the next `Company` to the next row, instead of just repeating the first Company.

---

**UPDATE**: here is more of my code:

```
std::vector<LPWSTR> Columns;
std::vector<LPWSTR> TableData;
std::vector<Company> companiesInGame;

Company company1(L"American Gas Co", L"1930", L"ACG", 2000000, 500000);
Company company2(L"TruGrocers", L"1940", L"TRG", 1525000, 300000);
Company company3(L"Northern Airlines", L"1929", L"NAR", 1500000, 220000);
Company company4(L"Jackson Estates", L"1938", L"JAE", 1970000, 255000);
Company company5(L"High Point Hotels", L"1920", L"HPH", 970000, 250000);
Company company6(L"Chucker's Truckers", L"1940", L"CHT", 600000, 100000);

companiesInGame.push_back(company1);
companiesInGame.push_back(company2);
companiesInGame.push_back(company3);
companiesInGame.push_back(company4);
companiesInGame.push_back(company5);
companiesInGame.push_back(company6);

for (int i = 0; i < companiesInGame.size(); i++)
{
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].CompanyNameBuffer);
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].CompanyCodeBuffer);
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].YearEstablishedBuffer);
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].TotalNetWorthBuffer);
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].TotalSharesBuffer);
    TableData.push_back(companiesInGame[i].PricePerShareBuffer);
}
```

```
Company::Company(std::wstring CompanyName, std::wstring YearEstablished, std::wstring CompanyCode, double TotalNetWorth, int TotalShares)
{
    this->companyName = CompanyName;
    this->yearEstablished = YearEstablished;

    this->iCompanyNetWorth = TotalNetWorth;
    this->iTotalShares = TotalShares;

    //Format character arrays for Printing
    CompanyName.copy(CompanyNameBuffer, 100);
    YearEstablished.copy(YearEstablishedBuffer, 100);
    CompanyCode.copy(CompanyCodeBuffer, 100);
    SetStockInfo();

    size_t CompanyNameBufferLength = CompanyName.length();
    CompanyNameBuffer[CompanyNameBufferLength] = '\0';

    size_t YearEstablishedBufferLength = YearEstablished.length();
    YearEstablishedBuffer[YearEstablishedBufferLength] = '\0';

    size_t CompanyCodeBufferLength = CompanyCode.length();
    CompanyCodeBuffer[CompanyCodeBufferLength] = '\0';

    //Convert integer values to string for Printing
    swprintf_s(TotalNetWorthBuffer, 20, L"$ %lf", TotalNetWorth);
    swprintf_s(TotalSharesBuffer, 20, L"%d", TotalShares);
    swprintf_s(PricePerShareBuffer, 20, L"$ %.2lf", this->iPricePerShare);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show how your `TableData` is being populated, and how it relates to `companiesInGame`.  However, one issue I see is that when you are sending `LVM_INSERTITEM`, you are setting `tableCell.mask = LVIF_TEXT` but you are not resetting `tableCell.pszText` or `tableCell.cchTextMax`, so `LVM_INSERTITEM` will carry over the text from the previous `LVN_SETITEM` message.

---

**UPDATE**:

The kind of duplication you are experiencing usually indicates that you are reusing the same memory buffer multiple times.  But I don't see that in your code (though, what you have shown is hardly a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though).

That being said, I would suggest getting rid of `TableData` and the inner loop altogether, you don't really need them.  For example:

```
size_t numRows = companiesInGame.size();
LVITEM tableCell = { 0 };

for (int x = 0; x < numRows; ++x)
{
    const Company &company = companiesInGame[i];

    tableCell.iItem = x;
    tableCell.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    tableCell.iSubItem = 0;
    tableCell.pszText = company.CompanyNameBuffer;
    ListView_InsertItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);

    tableCell.iSubItem = 1;
    tableCell.pszText = company.CompanyCodeBuffer;
    ListView_SetItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);

    tableCell.iSubItem = 2;
    tableCell.pszText = company.YearEstablishedBuffer;
    ListView_SetItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);

    tableCell.iSubItem = 3;
    tableCell.pszText = company.TotalNetWorthBuffer;
    ListView_SetItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);

    tableCell.iSubItem = 4;
    tableCell.pszText = company.TotalSharesBuffer;
    ListView_SetItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);

    tableCell.iSubItem = 5;
    tableCell.pszText = company.PricePerShareBuffer;
    ListView_SetItem(ListCompanyInfoTable, &tableCell);
}
```

Alternatively, I would suggest using the ListView in [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) instead, ie give it the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style and then handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification, eg:

```
ListView_SetItemCountEx(ListCompanyInfoTable, companiesInGame.size(), 0);

...

// in your parent window's WndProc:
switch (uMsg)
{
    ...
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        NMHDR *nmhdr = reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(lParam);
        if (nmhdr->hwndFrom == ListCompanyInfoTable &&
            nmhdr->code == LVN_GETDISPINFOW)
        {
            NMLVDISPINFOW* pdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFOW*>(lParam);
            if (pdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
            {
                const Company &company = companiesInGame[pdi->item.iItem];
                switch (pdi->item.iSubItem)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.CompanyNameBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.CompanyCodeBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.YearEstablishedBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.TotalNetWorthBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.TotalSharesBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        lstrcpynW(pdi->item->pszText, company.PricePerShareBuffer, pdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tabledata is an std::vector<LPWSTR> of buffers. Each buffer is a wchar_t variable to display each company's data. So how would I reset pszText/cchTextMax in my loop? Because it appears in my debugging that they are automatically being set correctly in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: "*So how would I reset pszText/cchTextMax in my loop?*" - in the outer loop, just set them to NULL/0, or remove the `LVIF_TEXT` flag, use that only in the inner loop. But, why are you using `TableData` at all, instead of just reading values directly from `companiesInGame` in your loops? What does `companiesInGame` actually look like? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] showing how you are preparing the data you want to display.

Comment: Added more code... Hopefully that explains a bit.

Comment: Why is `Company` using `wchar_t[]` buffers instead of `std::wstring`? I would suggest getting rid of `TableData` and the inner loop completely, and just have the outer loop iterate through `companiesInGame` directly. Alternatively, use the ListView in [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) (ie apply the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style), or use the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` feature on each cell, and then handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification to provide cell text whenever the ListView asks for it dynamically.

Comment: Hi, the buffers are mainly for trial purposes. As you suggested, I needed to handle LVN_GETDISPINFO message. Now I can add as many companies as I want and the table will resize itself. Thank you!